# Present uiviewcontroller from ParentViewController in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xlpagertabstrip

I have a parentview which has 2 child views, I am trying to show a uiviewcontroller as "Present modally" I use the following code:

```
class ParentCtrl: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {
    let obj = ChildCtrl()
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        obj.someClassMethod()
    }
}

class ChildCtrl: UIViewController, IndicatorInfoProvider {
   struct Storyboard {
    static let segue_id = "segue_id"
}
   public func someClassMethod(){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Storyboard.segue_id, sender: self)
    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == Storyboard.segue_id){
            let destino = segue.destination as! NewViewController
            destino.seleccion = seleccion
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

has no segue with identifier 'segue_id''
But Yeah, I have that identifier because if I copy:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Storyboard.segue_id, sender: self)
```

in the viewDidload method the NewViewController is presented

How can I solve that?

Comment: storyboard segue ?

Comment: If `NewViewController` is being presented, what is the issue then?

Comment: You must specify the `segue_id` in the `storyboard` while creating the `segue`.

Comment: @Tobi I edited my question, I create a struct

Comment: @PGDev yes I specified in the storyboard, my error is when 
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Storyboard.segue_id, sender: self)
is called in someClassMethod()

Comment: What is the value of `Storyboard.segue_id`?

Comment: @PGDev segue_id, see my struct and that name is the same in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Specify the **Storyboard Segue identifier**, i.e.

[image]

And use this id while writing the code to perform segue, i.e.

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_id", sender: self)
```

**Edit:**

Create `obj` from `storyboard`, i.e.

```
let obj = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildCtrl") as! ChildCtrl
```

Comment: Yes I did that, when I call this:
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Storyboard.segue_id, sender: self) in my viewDidLoad I don't get error, but When I call from my parentview I get the error

Comment: Is there any segue connecting from `ParentCtrl` to `NewViewController`.

Comment: What is the class of of the controller in storyboard? Is it `ChildCtrl` or `ParentCtrl`?

Comment: ChildCtrl, I use XLPagerTabStrip lib Where I set the ParentCtrl and that has the ChildCtrl, this is the scene

I am trying to access a method from my childCtrl, see my code

Comment: Is `ChildCtrl` embedded in `ParentCtrl`?

Comment: yes, like this override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
        var child: UIViewController
            child = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildCtrl")
        return [child]
    }

Comment: I get this : whose view is not in the window hierarchy! in my self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Storyboard.segue_id, sender: self) in my someclassmethod

Answer (score 0):

You are simply creating an instance of `ChildCtrl` rather than using the instance that came from the storyboard. As a result, that instance doesn't know anything about any storyboard file and therefore has no context to perform a segue.

You need to perform the segue *from the instance of `ChildCtrl` that is on screen*.

Comment: I get this : whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Don’t call methods on child view controllers in `viewDidLoad`. Call in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: I am trying to call this someClassMethod() that is out from viewdidload or viewdidappear method

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question. Show your storyboard and how the various view controllers are created and exactly how you are calling the various functions

Comment: When I copy this line self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Storyboard.segue_id, sender: self) in my childctrl viedidload() the newviewctrl is show but I want to access from my parent view there I got the error

Comment: Have you tried it in `viewDidAppear()` because that's the point where all the views have completely loaded !